# Write in html with variables, then reset to default

Tags: c#, html

im trying to edit an HTML i have created.
having the user typing something into the text box it will change the value but then I want it to reset.
I got the part of making the text change but it stays like that and when i try it for the 2nd time it does not work without me manually editing the .html file
here's my code:

```
const string fileName = "txt.html";


var content = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
content = content.Replace("{0}", textBox1.Text);

File.WriteAllText(fileName, content);

Process.Start(fileName);
```

I tried adding something like this after that code but its just opening with the variable ' {0} '

```
var content2 = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
content2 = content2.Replace(textBox1.Text, "{0}");
File.WriteAllText(fileName, content2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a template html file, every time replace value using that template

```
 const string fileName = "txt.html";
 const string templateFileName = "txtTemplate.html";    

var content = File.ReadAllText(templateFileName );
content = content.Replace("{0}", textBox1.Text);

File.WriteAllText(fileName, content);

Process.Start(fileName);
```

Comment: so you need two htmls files?
thanks this actually works in my head now !